# Is it possible to refer to an external .hgrc file?

Tags: mercurial

Is there any way for me to refer to an external configuration in Mercurial? Our repository is on a shared drive so at the moment the last user to use it is the username it keeps since by default hgrc is under the `.hg` folder local to the repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could place one in the root of your home directory.

According to the [man page](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html), the following locations are checked for per-user configuration files.

> ```
>    (Unix) $HOME/.hgrc
>    (Windows) %USERPROFILE%\.hgrc
>    (Windows) %USERPROFILE%\Mercurial.ini
>    (Windows) %HOME%\.hgrc
>    (Windows) %HOME%\Mercurial.ini
> ```

In your per user .hgrc you can have a section like this:

```
[ui]
username =Your Name<example@example.com>
```

When you commit and push, the push destinations in .hg/hgrc will be used and your username from the per user file will be used for the commit.

Also, you should consider sharing your repository in a way other then a shared drive. hg lets you pull and push from each computer with a repository and if you need the notion of a 'central repo' you could put it behind hgweb.cgi and push via https or ssh

Answer (score 3):

I agree completely with Daniel — each user should configure the username in his personal config file. The `.hg/hgrc` file should not contain a username.

However, let me answer your question about include files: you can include one configuration file in another with:

```
%include some/file
```

See the [hgrc(5) man page](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html).